# How to use two meta_compare in an array?

Tags: php, post-meta, array

I want to use two `meta_compare` in an array.

```
// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 150,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'meta_key'     => 'usp-custom-1',
            'meta_value'   => array('question','money', 'health','relationships'),
            'meta_compare' => 'IN',
            'meta_compare' => '!=',
        ),
    ),
    'author' =>  $_GET["id"],
    'order'  => 'DESC'
));
```

But it doesn't work.

What I want to achieve is show posts that's NOT equal to these 4 meta_values.

I know I'm probably making a slight mistake somewhere along the lines.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `'meta_compare' => 'NOT IN',`?

Comment: this is going to be a very expensive/heavy/slow query. Post meta tables weren't designed for searches, and asking the database to exclude results is very expensive/slow. `usp-custom-1` would make much more sense as a taxonomy, that would mitigate a lot of the performance and scaling issues.

Comment: Hey Buttered_Toast, for some reason `'meta_compare' => 'NOT IN'` still displays posts from all those 4 meta values.

Comment: Tom J Nowell, I agree, but I couldn't think any other way. But I will definitely rethink my strategy, as I have already seen my website to load slower.

Comment: @robert0 when using `'meta_compare' => 'NOT IN'`, do you still have two `meta_compare`? because there should be only one, the `'meta_compare' => 'NOT IN'`

Comment: I use just one. `'meta_compare' => 'NOT IN'` . When I use NOT IN, it shows all posts for that user. Posts that are with these meta values, and posts that doesn't have those values. I assume it should exclude posts with these meta values, right?

Comment: When I use just one meta value with `'meta_compare' => '!=',`. It does work great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this way is a bit long but it will get the job done.

We can use multiple meta_value checks with AND relation

```
// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 150,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'usp-custom-1',
            'value'   => 'question',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'usp-custom-1',
            'value'   => 'money',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'usp-custom-1',
            'value'   => 'health',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'usp-custom-1',
            'value'   => 'relationships',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
    ),
    'author' =>  $_GET["id"],
    'order'  => 'DESC'
));
```

You need to check the performance hit for this query because it can be resouce heavy.

I alos noticed `$_GET["id"]`, you passed it raw, I would suggest sanitizing/validating every value that was passed to you (values that you did not pass yourself, like user input or url queries).

By the property name I assume that it will be a id, so we can sanitize it like this

```
'author' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
```

Comment: thanks, but for some reason it still output all posts (including with these meta values as well). In fact, even when I use only one array in  your `'meta_query'`. It still output all posts for that user. But when I don't use `'meta_query'` array, it does work.

Comment: @robert0 hahaha ok i found the problem... its not `meta_compare` its just `compare`, updated my answer, it goes to all the meta arrays, no `meta_` as prefix. I even think that if you will fix your original arguments it will work fine =], let m eknow

Comment: Brilliant! it worked, thanks a ton! Appreciate your help and time spent. thanks again!

Comment: Looks like without using `meta_` prefix, did the job with `NOT IN` as well. Thanks again Buttered_Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like without using `meta_` prefix, did the job with `NOT IN` as well:

```
    // get posts
    $posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 150,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'usp-custom-1',
            'value'   => array(  'question','money', 'health','relationships'  ),
            'compare' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
    'author' =>  $_GET["id"],
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));
```

Thanks to @Buttered_Toast for figuring this out.

Comment: Great, I thought it would work. I think you better use this option instead of mine. This is cleaner and im pretty sure less resources demanding. Glad I could help =]